# How to structure a multi-page chrome app?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-app

I'm building a file for each 'page' I want to dynamically load.  Each 'page' file is implemented using the [Singleton Pattern](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#singletonpatternjavascript), with pretty much just one public method, `loadPage()` or `init()`.

Is there a better way to approach this?  A framework that I should know of?  It's not a complicated app, maybe 3-5pages.  It just started to become a real pain `document.createElement`-ing several nested div's with JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the contents of the body with an assignment to innerHtml and take that HTML from a file inside the app folder.

Comment: Might be a jarring experience though as the HTML is re-parsed each time. Maybe having several top-level content `<div>`s with only one visible at a time is better, possibly even with something like fade transitions between them.

Comment: Yes. Assigning to the innerHtml of sibling divs would work well.